# DJANGO order_by before pagination

Tags: django, sorting, get, pagination

This is code listing tasks and sorting them by three conditions desc and asc. 
I have two problems now, which is that: 
1) the order_by is only applied on the first page. I would like it so that order_by is run and then the entire ordered list is paginated.
2) the "_pressed" arrow images are never shown.
 
Please help! Thanks!

VIEW.PY

```
def task_list(request, **kwargs):
    q = Task.objects.all()
    if 'sort' in request.GET:
        sort_by = request.GET['sort']
    else:
        sort_by = 'latest-desc'

    if sort_by == 'latest-desc':
        q = q.order_by('-pub_date')

    if sort_by == 'latest-asc':
        q = q.order_by('pub_date')

    if sort_by == 'price-desc':
        q = q.order_by('-price')

    if sort_by == 'price-asc':
        q = q.order_by('price')

    if sort_by == 'deadline-desc':
        q = q.order_by('-expiry_date')

    if sort_by == 'deadline-asc':
        q = q.order_by('expiry_date')

    kwargs['queryset'] = q.all()

    return list_detail.object_list(request, **kwargs)
```

URL.PY

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tasks/$', 'tasks.views.task_list', 
         {'template_name':'findtask.html', 'paginate_by':4}, name='tasks'),
)
```

HTML

```
<div class="sortList">
<ul>
<li class="sort">Sort by latest
<a href="?sort=latest-desc">{% if request.GET.sort == 'latest-desc' %}<img src="/static/img/downarrow_pressed.gif"/>{% endif %}
{% if request.GET.sort != 'latest-desc' %}<img src="/static/img/downarrow.gif"/>{% endif %}</a> 
<a href="?sort=latest-asc">{% if request.GET.sort == 'latest-asc' %}<img src="/static/img/uparrow_pressed.gif"/>{% endif %}
{% if request.GET.sort != 'latest-asc' %}<img src="/static/img/uparrow.gif"/>{% endif %}</a></li>
<li class="sort">Sort by deadline
<a href="?sort=deadline-desc">{% if request.GET.sort == 'deadline-desc' %}<img src="/static/img/downarrow_pressed.gif" />{% endif %}
{% if request.GET.sort != 'deadline-desc' %}<img src="/static/img/downarrow.gif" />{% endif %}</a>
<a href="?sort=deadline-asc">{% if request.GET.sort == 'deadline-asc' %}<img src="/static/img/uparrow_pressed.gif" />{% endif %}
{% if request.GET.sort != 'deadline-asc' %}<img src="/static/img/uparrow.gif" />{% endif %}</a></li>
<li class="sort">Sort by price
<a href="?sort=price-desc">{% if request.GET.sort == 'price-desc' %}<img src="/static/img/downarrow_pressed.gif" />{% endif %}
{% if request.GET.sort != 'price-desc' %}<img src="/static/img/downarrow.gif" />{% endif %}</a>
<a> <a href="?sort=price-asc">{% if request.GET.sort == 'price-asc' %}<img src="/static/img/uparrow_pressed.gif" /> {% endif %}
{% if request.GET.sort != 'price-asc' %}<img src="/static/img/uparrow.gif" />{% endif %}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

About second question. If [django.core.context_processors.request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS?

Check if {{request.GET}} returns something.

About first. Maybe problem in here:

```
kwargs['queryset'] = q.all()
```

Try this:

```
kwargs['queryset'] = q
```

And you need to trace what in q in the begining and end of your view

Comment: yup that was the problem! context_processors worked. first question is still unresolved though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your template file `findtask.html`, especially the part of generating URLs links for pages. I doubt the links are incorrectly missing the `sort` argument.
2. Check [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) in settings file, is [the request processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) there? Accessing non-exist variable in template will not raise error in Django now.